# Остались ли в интернете исходники python os project?

Tags: python, ос, download

Я обыскал весь интернет, но так ничего и не нашел.
Об этом проекте я узнал в этом треде форума Linux: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/talks/7870469
Их единственный сайт не работает.

Comment: На битбакете они как лежали, так и лежат до сих пор https://bitbucket.org/pythonos/pythonos

Comment: (правда, Bitbucket обещал удалить все Mercurial-репозитории, так что лучше не тянуть со скачиванием)

Comment: @andreymal, (оффтопик) надо поставить себе напоминание на май, чтобы последний свой репозиторий с bitbucket мигрировать)